# Django : Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django

Whenever I try to log in with username and password this happens:
[image]

my project name is:corey_schafer

app name for user stuff is: users

projects urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('register/', include('users.urls'))
]
```

users urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.register, name='register'),
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

users views.py:

```
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

if views.py image not showing please go here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/auZxo.png

if any other file is needed to solve this problem please let me know

Comment: Did you forgot to include [app_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) parameter in users urls.py?

Answer (score 0):

You url basically needs to have only register/login/ path rather than two /logins.
Your path defined is first go to register.urls and inside that go match and go to login as per the URLs files mentioned above. Whereas the path in the question that you are trying to access says go to register then login and login again which isn't available, thus 404!

Comment: I got the problem.but what is the solution?

Comment: In the very first line I told you the solution. Hit the url http://localhost:8000/register/login/ instead of what you are hitting right now. You need to edit your frontend code accordingly so that it hits the right url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [app_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) parameter in users urls.py in order to be able to have `redirect` automatically use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to correct view under the hood.